# Declaring a function in TypeScript which itself is the result of a function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In regular JS, you can do something like this:

```
function ConstructorFunc() {

    function innerFunc(){ console.log("hello"); }

    // Modify innerFunc prototype here...

    return innerFunc;

}

var MyFunc = ConstructorFunc();

MyFunc();
> hello
```

but how can I do this in TypeScript as the following doesn't work

```
export function MyFunc = ConstructorFunc();
```

NB: ConstructorFunc in my actual project comes from a third party library so can't be changed, I just simplified it here for the sake of simplifying the question.

Comment: If the function actually comes from a third-party non-TypeScript library, wouldn't that mean you'd just want to make a .tsd (TypeScript Definition) file, so your TypeScript knows it exists? Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var MyFunc = ConstructorFunc();
export MyFunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for your third party library that specifies the type of ConstructorFunc. Something like this:

```
interface ThirdPartyLibraryName {
    ConstructorFunc? (): () => any
}
```

You'll have to change this definition if any of the functions have parameters or return types as necessary. Because you said you simplified it, I can't provide the exact definition required.